# Javascript Prototype chaining change the target

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

I am a student studying programming.

I have a question.

```
    function a () {

    }

    a.prototype.prtSomething = function(arg) { console.log(arg); }

    function b () {

    }

    var myObj = new b();
```

If I want to use the method of a in myObj, we use this code.

```
b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);
b.prototype.constructor = b;
```

That means changing the target of scope chaining.
But why don't we use this code?

```
b.prototype.__proto__ = a.prototype;
```

I think there must be a reason to creating and using a new object.
but I don't know.
Please teach me.
Thank you.

Comment: There is a typo in the last code line: b.prtotype --> b.prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For at least one good reason: the `__proto__` feature is deprecated, so you shouldn't use it for future compatibility.

I recommend reading [MDN page on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), and also linked pages on inheritance if you are learning.

USEFUL ADDITIONAL NOTE:
using `b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);` is a way to simulate Class inheritance in a prototype way (b inherits from a) without the "parent" (a) constructor to be called. If you would rather prefer to simulate inheritance with "parent" constructor being called, you can use `b.prototype = new a();`

Of course it's a emulation of class behavior, it differs in details because prototypes are not classes, for example you can dynamically add functions to `a`'s prototype **after** an instance of `b` has been created, and the new function will be available for the instance because it works by reference. In a similar way the second example doesn't execute `a`'s constructor for every further instance, but only once when you assign it to `b`'s prototype.

Actually I find prototypes really powerful when you get to know them, allows many combinations.

```js
function a () {
    console.log('a constructor');
}

a.prototype.prtSomething = function(arg) { console.log(arg); }

function b () {
    console.log('b constructor');
}

b.prototype = Object.create(a.prototype);
b.prototype.constructor = b;

var myObj = new b();
```

```js
function a () {
    console.log('a constructor');
}

a.prototype.prtSomething = function(arg) { console.log(arg); }

function b () {
    console.log('b constructor');
}

b.prototype = new a();
b.prototype.constructor = b;

var myObj = new b();
```